# Is it possible to join an unrelated table in an EF Core Include query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have an EF Core code first project and have created the following table

```
[Table("Activity")]
public class Activity : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public TransactionType Type { get; set; }
    public virtual ActivityItem Item { get; set; }
}
```

`ActivityItem` is an abstract class that doesn't map to its own table, but I have three separate models that all inherit from it.

```
//Not its own table in the database
public abstract class ActivityItem
{}

[Table("ClassA")]
public class ClassA : ActivityItem
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

[Table("ClassB")]
public class ClassB : ActivityItem
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

[Table("ClassC")]
public class ClassC : ActivityItem
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

In this particular instance I'm explicitly avoiding the Table-Per-Hierarchy scheme because I need to have `ClassA`, `ClassB`, and `ClassC` as there own unique tables in the database.

Whenever I'm querying an entry from my `Activity` table I use the `Type` property to indicate if the `Item` is either an instance of `ClassA`, `ClassB`, or `ClassC`.

Is there a way that I can still use the `Include` method when I'm forming my queries to populate the `Item` navigation property?

#### Current Solution

```
var activity = _context.Activity.Where(...).FirstOrDefault();

if (activity.Type == "ClassA")
    activity.Item = _context.ClassA.First(p => p.Id == activity.ActivityId);
else if (activity.Type == "ClassB")
    activity.Item = _context.ClassB.First(p => p.Id == activity.ActivityId);
else if (activity.Type == "ClassC")
    activity.Item = _context.ClassC.First(p => p.Id == activity.ActivityId);
```

#### Desired Solution

```
var activity = _context.Activity.Include(p => p.Item).Where(...).FirstOrDefault();
```

I know EF Core will write Join queries on the related table when you use the `Include` method, but in my case there is no related table since `ActivityItem` isn't represented in the database. Is there a way to explicitly specify which table to Join based on my custom `Type` field without resorting to the Table-Per-Hierarchy scheme?

Comment: If you want to get the data in one query you'd have to do Left Joins to each table, which kinda defeats the purpose of having one `ActivityId` with a `Type`.  You could instead have one FK to each table that is nullable with corresponding navigation properties and then you'd be able to Include them all and you'd have to figure out the type by which one is not null.  Basically a relational DB cannot exactly model inheritance.

Comment: Alternatively you might want to consider a solution where you have one Activity table and it would contain the information that determines whatever differences there are between each activity.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a table of Activities, and a predicate that filters zero or more Activities from this table. You are only interested in the first Activity that passes the filter. There might be no Activity at all that might pass the filter, hence the OrDefault.

This fetched Activity has a (string?) property Type. The value of this property depicts whether you should look in table ClassA / ClassB / ClassC.

The fetched Activity also has a property ActivityId. You want the first (or default) ActivityItem (ClassA / ClassB / ClassC), that has an Id equal to this ActivityId.

Your design makes that property `ActivityId` is not a proper foreign key to the `ActivityItem` that this `Activity` belongs to. In fact your foreign key is a combination of `[Type, ActivityId]`.

So what you need, is a method that concatenates all your `ClassA / ClassB / ClassC` into one sequence, remembering the `Type`. After that you can join on `[Type, Id]`.

If you have to do this only once, you can use the following. If you have to do this to solve several problems, consider creating extension methods.

```
var activityItems = dbContext.ClassAItems.Cast<ActivityItem>()
    .Select(classAItem => new
    {
        Type = "ClassA",
        Data = classAItem,
    })
.Concat(dbContext.ClassBItems.Cast<ActivityItem>()
    .Select(classBItem => new
    {
        Type = "ClassB",
        Data = classBItem,
    }))
.Concat(dbContext.ClassCItems.Cast<ActivityItem>()
    .Select(classCItem => new
    {
        Type = "ClassC",
        Data = classCItem,
    }));
```

Now you can just do an inner join:

```
// join the filtered activities with the activityitems:
var result = dbContext.Activities.Where(...)
    .Join(activityItems,

    activity => new                     // from each activity take [type, activityId]
    {
        Type = activity.Type
        Id = activity.ActivityId,
    }
    activityItem => new                 // from each ActivityItems take [Type, Id]
    {
        Type = activityItem.Type,
        Id = activityItem.Data.Id,
    }

    // when these keys match, use the Activity and the matching ActivityItem to make one new
    // well, in this case, you are only interested in the Data of the ActivityItem
    (activity, activityItem) => activityItem.Data)

    // From the joined items you only want the first:
    .FirstOrDefault();
```